# How can I set an alarm on all my Android devices at once for free?

Tags: alarm

I would like to be able to set an alarm on all my Android devices at once.

The application [Timely Alarm Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely) has this feature ("*Cloud synchronization enables a seamless experience across phones and tablets.*") but the latter costs $2.5.

Are there any free alternatives?

Comment: You could create an event in the Google calendar. Provided all your devices are synced, that should trigger all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try to **not** read this as "is there an app...", as that would be off-topic according to our guidelines (see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details).

<s>So apart from looking for a different app to save some peanuts, you could live with the ads (according to its description, the app is available for free with ads; there's no note to the cloud feature being restricted to payment, neither does the [related description on the product's webpage](http://www.bitspin.ch/#section_connect_anchor), nor the FAQ on [How can I synchronize my devices](http://www.bitspin.ch/support#answer_12) mention that).</s>
<sup>according to Krampus' comment below, the cloud functionality seems to be restricted to "premium users" indeed, though none of the material cited says so</sup>

Alternatively, there is the possibility to utilize a synchronized calendar (like the *Google Calendar*) for that: Create an event, which then is synchronized across your devices. So the alert should trigger on all of them.

Comment: I use (and love) Timely. Because I wanted the cloud sync so bad I ponied up for the in-app payment.

Comment: @Krampus so it doesn't work without upgrading? Reading all the app's descriptions (even the FAQ, as my answer states), I've found no hint this were reserved for "premium users" (in fact, while the desc on play talks about "premium features", it names not a single one belonging to that).

Comment: The app works fine for free, but if you want to sync your alarms to all your devices that costs extra.